# swc / I need a global variable for the duration of the plugin

Tags: swc, swc-compiler

I am creating an SWC plugin. I will be as brief as possible. The user can style HTML (jsx) elements with attributes.

```
<div background="red">123</div>
```

The plugin adds a class attribute with a unique id.

```
<div className="style642">123</div>
```

And creates a css file with all found styles

**my problem:**
swc does not allow you to read files. I can't add new styles to css when they are found. I can only completely replace the contents of a file

```
fs::write("test.css", data).expect("Unable to write file");
```

I created a global variable

```
pub struct TransformVisitor {    
    styles:String,
}
```

**When I find the style attribute, I put the style on that line, and write the whole line to a file**

But this variable is cleared for each component.

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
            <>
                 <MyComp></MyComp>
                 <p background={"red"}>123</p>
            </>
   )}
```

**During the processing of "MyComp", the styles of the "Home" component will be removed.
Only the styles of one component remain in the file.**

Help me please. I need a global variable for the duration of the plugin, or any advice.